# How to get films starring for one actor in dbpedia sparql?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, querying

I have the following code where I get the starring for all films selected:

```
SELECT ?f ?starring
WHERE {
?f rdf:type dbo:Film .
?f dbo:starring ?starring
}
```

Is there a way where I can get films of specific starring (actor) like "Tom Hanks" for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the DBpedia resource representing the actor, as the object of the tipple pattern:

```
SELECT ?f 
WHERE {
?f rdf:type dbo:Film .
?f dbo:starring dbr:Tom_Hanks .
}
```

Comment: Thanks I got it working, but can you check the Edit above. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Never mind I got it working, Thanks. I had to use the prefix "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>" instead of "PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology>"

Comment: Please exploit the power of Linked Data by sharing SPARQL Query results using results page URIs (hyperlinks) :)